# Expect script output at Perl console

Tags: perl, expect

I have a exp script  -script.exp to enter a name and password. it calls test.sh file like below.

```
set timeout -1
spawn ./test.sh -create
match_max 100000
expect -exact "Enter the name: "
send -- "abcd\r"
expect -exact "\r
Please confirm password: "
send -- "xxy\r"
expect -exact "\r
expect eof
```

It gives me a output at expect window -
"Successfully entered the name"
if some issue there it throws exception or error message.

I run this expect script in a Perl file-- like below

```
$cmd="expect script.exp";
system($cmd);
$outputfromexp=?
```

I need a output of fail or passed status of *exp at Perl console* after running the script.

How can i do this? Please help me.

I tried calling as suggested  in my Perl script--

```
use strict;
use warnings;
    sub sysrun {
            my ($command) ="expect script.exp";
            my $ret_code;

            $ret_code = system("$command");
            if ( $ret_code == 0 ) {
                    # Job suceeded
                    $ret_code = 1;
            }
            else {
                    # Job Failed
                    $ret_code = 0;
            }
            return ($ret_code);
    }

    my $ret_code=sysrun();

    print "reuturmsfg- $ret_code\n";
```

But its printing nothing-- just reuturmsfg-.

I made the changes-

```
my $ret_code=sysrun();
```

it gives me 0 and 1 return code.

Comment: ***Always*** `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program. ***Never*** use ampersands `&` to call Perl subroutines.

Comment: I used strict and warnings. and removed & even though no output at $ret_code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, to get the return code you want to do:

```
system($cmd);
my $ret_code = $?;
```

To get STDOUT output from the execution:

```
my @out = `$cmd`;
my $ret_code = $?;
```

I strongly suggest using strict and warnings in your code.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Pavel, I updated my question. With your suggestion, please look into and help me..

Comment: I used my $ret_code = system($cmd) but no out put. pls help

Comment: Um. Trying to understand why my answer was down voted?

Comment: @ Pavel- I am getting success code -1. Wow. Thanks you. thank you,

Comment: Made green for the answer.